# Is Eclipse more robust than Netbeans for Java web programming?

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, jakarta-ee

I am looking at learning to program a Java EE/SE web application with the following components:

- JBoss
- nHibernate
- JSTL

I'm sure there are other pieces.  That's all I know at the moment.  Would I be better off, with Netbeans or Eclipse?  Netbeans always seemed more friendly to me but I've never made anything big with it.  I wanted to start fresh.  Using the technologies I mentioned is there any advantage to one or the other?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using JBoss then there is Eclipse support directly:

- [JBoss Tools](http://www.jboss.org/tools.html) - which gives you JSF/JPA/JBoss support
- [JBoss Developer Studio](http://community.jboss.org/en/tools/blog/2010/10/21/jboss-developer-studio-4-beta-now-available) - very new, in beta, but provides a customized Eclipse environment.

I think the O/S definitely has a big impact on the stability of the IDE.  Under Ubuntu 10 I don't see Eclipse crash that often.  I can't speak for Netbeans unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

I use both platforms concurrently on different projects, they share a lot of features mapped to similar short cuts and you would really only need a few hours of practise to be very productive in one after moving to the other.

Netbeans positives are that it seems a more polished platform and I use it for all "straight up" development.

Eclipse has a wider range of plugins, and I use eclipse where I need some specific plug-in. 
Sometimes it feels a bit unstable and some of the plug-ins feel experimental, but the core stuff is great.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'm using Eclipse (currently the Spring Source Tool Suite distribution).
I would recommend using one of the numerous Eclipse distribution matching your needs.
 As for JBoss support, go with @Jon recommendation for supported plug-ins (I'm using JBoss Tools and it's working great).

Answer (score 0):

I currently am working with Netbeans on a Java, Stripes, Hibernate, JSP, & JSTL project. I think it works great!